# Random array with random range and functions

Tags: java, arrays, random, methods, median

How would I create a program that fills an array with random integers, with the number of integers and the possible range of the integers chosen by the user. And then once the user is presented a menu offering to do some calculations with the numbers like mean, median, mode, range, standard deviation... ect

Comment: We would not do your homework.

Comment: `Math.random()`, `int[]`, `int`, `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)`, Creating methods, basic class creation, basic math computational skills. All you need.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this is for an assignment, so Im going to suggest the process you use to solve your problem.

1. You first talked about creating an array of n elements chosen by the user. That means you need to get input from the user in some way. I would recommend using the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class to prompt the user and store it in a variable.
2. Next you need to create the array using the variable you created in the last step.
3. After that you need to prompt the user again asking for the range of values. I suggest asking for the lower limit, then the upper limit, storing each in their own variables.
4. Next you need to loop through each index and store a random value there between your lower limit and upper limit. Again, my recommendation is the [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class. You will need to find out how to generate the numbers based on your range. (hint; lower limit plus a random number between 0 and the upper limit minus the lower limit)
5. Finally, you need to loop through your array again and do the calculations based on what the user enters. Use the Scanner class again and ask them what calculation they want to do. From there, use an if statement to invoke the right calculation.